# How do I make selenium wait for a specific tag show up

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am uploading an image, and I used time.sleep(3) to make it finish upload. But sometimes 3 seconds isn't enough. I am not sure how the code should look like to make slenium to check for a specific tag is shown, then continue to do something.

```
#input image path
try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/h5/ul/li[1]/div[2]/ul/li/form[1]/input[5]")))
            element.send_keys('C:\\1.png')
            print("Add actionImageURL 1: " + str(element.get_attribute('value')))
        except Exception:
            print("actionImageURL 1 Path Failed")
#click upload button        
try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/h5/ul/li[1]/div[2]/ul/li/form[1]/input[6]")))
            element.click()
            print("actionImageURL 1 Uploading...")
            #maybe here is where i can do find for the tag and do a loop wait?
            images = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('img-thumbnail ng-hide')
            previewlink = images.get_attribute('src')
            print(previewlink)
            if preview == 't.notInPlaceActionImageURL_preview':
                print('Link: ' + print(previewlink))
                time.sleep(3)
            print("actionImageURL 1 Uploaded")
        except Exception:
            print("actionImageURL 1 Upload Button NOT FOUND")
```

I do not know how to deal with html tag like this, see before and after when image is done uploading:

Before:
[image: Before upload image]

After:
[image: After image complete upload, url will show up, and html tag changes]

implicit might solve my problem, but i am looking to workaround with the tag, and how do deal with tag like those. Thanks

Comment: I can see you are already using EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,<>))). What issue you are facing when using same technique for your desired tag.

Comment: @rahulrai EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,<>))) isnt a issue, the issue comes after the second EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,<>))). After
`print("actionImageURL 1 Uploading...")`
What is does is upload an image, but there is a upload time. My python next step will jump out of the page which make upload fail, caz it was still uploading the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code a method to wait you can use that wait method in your project

```
private static WebElement waitForElement(By locator, int timeout)
{
    WebElement element=new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    return element;
}
```

The above code is wait method

If you want to use this method

---

`waitForElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"),50);`
This for example ,you can use your web element here

Comment: I am still pretty new to python, but i think your example is for Java?
I tried to use webdriverwait, i think thats what you meant:
https://pastebin.pl/view/2aaeeb1f
Please see my updated code, my error might be my class name is wong?